# The correct name for "height" of "direct" categories

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be a category. Then $C$ is said to be *direct* if $C$ has
no infinitely long descending sequence
$$
\cdots\to\bullet\to\bullet\to\bullet
$$
of non-identity morphisms in $C$.

Let $\mathrm{ON}$ denote the class of all ordinal numbers (in the sense of von Neumann), equipped with the
canonical irreflexive order $\in$, which makes $\mathrm{ON}$ a category. 
The category $C$ is direct if and only if it admits a identity-reflecting functor $C\to\mathord{\mathrm{ON}}$, or more explicitly, a map 
$\phi\colon\operatorname{Ob}(C)\to\mathord{\mathrm{ON}}$ such that any non-identity morphism $a\to b$ satisfies $\phi(a)<\phi(b)$.
Functions of this kind seems (but not surely) to be called "degree functions",
and makes $C$ a Reedy category with trivial degree-lowering component.
The names for directness and degree functions are taken from [nlab page for "direct category"](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/direct+category).

Now let $C$ be a direct category. Then there is the "smallest" degree function $\mathrm{ht}\colon C\to \mathrm{ON}$, in that
$$
\forall \phi\colon\text{degree function on $C$},\,
\forall a \in\operatorname{Ob}(C),\, \operatorname{ht}(a) \leq \phi(a) \text{.}
$$
This is easily defined by the well-founded induction on $\operatorname{Ob}(C)$ by
$$
\operatorname{ht}(a) :=
\left\{\operatorname{ht}(b)\,\middle|\,\text{There is a non-identity morphism }b\to a\right\}\text{.}
$$
**Question: Is there a name for this function?** This has the name *height function* (for posets) in order theory, but I could not find in the literature the terminology for the "height function" in this sense. I need to use this function in my paper, and I am not sure I am allowed to use the word "height" for this kind of concept.

Comment: This is more suitable for mathematics stack exchange than for mathoverflow, surely?

Comment: Terminological questions like this are fine on MO. It's recommended that you do your homework first. I'm not aware of a standard terminology, but I'm not very familiar with direct categories. As another possibility, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Rooted_tree), the term "depth" is used for this notion when studying trees. In the only reference on the MO page, Borisov uses the term "grading" for the functor $C \to ON$, so you could also say "minimal grading" or something. You might ask Borisov or Mike Shulman.

Comment: Another term that might show up is *rank* - at least in the set theory literature, this is exactly what you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this [article](http://home.sandiego.edu/~shulman/papers/reedy.pdf) by Mike Schulman, especially definition 4.6 where *height* is also used (for inverse categories but you can dualize that).

Comment: It's not obvious to me that the use of height in the linked article matches up with what the OP is describing, but I might be missing something . . .

Comment: Yep, the use of _height_ in this paper is more close to that of _degree function_ in the question.